# Any decent javascript code editor *control* for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

With syntax highlighting and intellisense if possible. Can be paid but better if free. What I need is a control/class/lib/dll that I can use in a Windows Forms project. I don't need a program. I'm using .net 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010. Working on C#.

Comment: Web control? Windows? WPF? What version of .NET?

Comment: I don't get this: "Windows Forms project, not a program" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the perfect solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/storm.aspx
Haven't tested much yet but seems to be just great.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [C# - Is there any WPF HTML/Javascript/CSS Syntax Editor Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509231/c-is-there-any-wpf-html-javascript-css-syntax-editor-control)